# Unit ball in $\ell^p$

Tags: real-analysis

$\text { Choose } 1 \leq p \leq \infty, \text { and let a closed unit ball } D=\left\{x \in \ell^{p}:\|x\|_{p} \leq 1\right\}$. I'm trying to show that $D$ is closed and bounded. The bounded part seems obvious since since it is contained in an open unit ball of finite radius. How to show the closed part? My attempt so far is to show if $\left\{x_{n}\right\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \text { is a sequence in } D \text { such that } x_{n} \rightarrow x \text { in }\ell^{p} \text { -norm, then } x \in D.$ How to show that? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Any point $x\notin D$ is inside the ball with center $x$ and radius $\|x-x/\|x\|_p\|_p/2$. Use triangle inequality to show that all points $y$ in this ball satisfy $\|y\|_p>1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $(x_n)_n$ is a sequence in $D$ with $x_n\to x$, then we have obviously $\Vert x_n \Vert 
\to \Vert x \Vert$ (this follows by reverse triangle inequality). Since $\Vert x_n \Vert \leq 1$ for all $n \geq 1$, we thus conclude $\Vert x \Vert \leq 1$, i.e. $x \in D$.

Alternatively, write $D$ as the inverse image of a closed set under the continuous map $x \mapsto \Vert x \Vert$ to see that $D$ is closed.

Answer (score 0):

A norm is always continuous in its own topology (specifically, Lipschitz continuous in the metric it induces), and your set is the preimage of $(-\infty,1]$.